# Apache Solr: sort by number of fields matching the query

Tags: sorting, solr

In my SOLR index I have documents that consist of many fields: `name`, `title`, `description`, `tags` etc. I would like to sort my documents by number of fields that match a query, but **do not want** to take into account how many times a matching term appears in a field (so no TFIDF, no BM25).

For example:

```
Documents:
ID: 100, title: "foo foo bar bar", name: "foo bar"
ID: 101, title: "foo bar", name: "gibberish foo"
ID: 102, title: "foo bar", name: "foo bar"
```

And when I search for "foo bar", I would like the results to be sorted in that order:

1. 102 (two fields matching)
2. 100 (also two fields matching, so 100 and 102 should be scored exactly the same)
3. 101 (one field matching)

How can I achieve this with SOLR? What should be the `sort` clause?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to disable term frequencies by using a constant score query like `(tags:stack)^=1`. Note that this is a special syntax. Then use the `eDisMax` query parser and specify in `qf` the fields, possibly with some boosting, and specify a value for `tie` like 1. This you need to make sure all subqueries (fields) are used for calculating the score.

This should do what you want, as more matching fields will result in a higher score, and term frequencies no longer used for scoring.